# JavaScript - detect swipe on button?

Tags: javascript, mobile, swipe

I have a button, of which i was wondering if you could (on mobile platforms) allow the user to hold and swipe up the button. Which results in a function being called:

button + (button swipe up) == call function

Would this be possible for mobile browsers. THANKS?!?

Comment: Sure, most libraries for mobile include "swipe up" events, so either use a library, or figure out how they do it.

Comment: @adeneo, could you recommend a source? (preferable not jQuery mobile)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this function, :

```
$(window).load(function(){
  detectswipe('btnid',myfunc);
});

function detectswipe(el,func) {
  swipe_det = new Object();
  swipe_det.sX = 0; swipe_det.sY = 0; swipe_det.eX = 0; swipe_det.eY = 0;
var min_x = 100;    //min x swipe for horizontal swipe
var max_x = 100;    //max x difference for vertical swipe
var min_y = 100;    //min y swipe for vertical swipe
var max_y = 100;    //max y difference for horizontal swipe
var direc = "";
ele = document.getElementById(el);
if(ele==null){
    return;
}
ele.addEventListener('touchstart',function(e){
    var t = e.touches[0];
    swipe_det.sX = t.screenX;
    swipe_det.sY = t.screenY;
},false);
ele.addEventListener('touchmove',function(e){
    var t = e.touches[0];
    swipe_det.eX = t.screenX;
    swipe_det.eY = t.screenY;
},false);
ele.addEventListener('touchend',function(e){
    if ((((swipe_det.eX - min_x > swipe_det.sX) || (swipe_det.eX + min_x < swipe_det.sX)) && ((swipe_det.eY < swipe_det.sY + max_y) && (swipe_det.sY > swipe_det.eY - max_y) && (swipe_det.eX > 0)))) {
        if(swipe_det.eX > swipe_det.sX) direc = "right";
        else direc = "left";
    }
    else if ((((swipe_det.eY - min_y > swipe_det.sY) || (swipe_det.eY + min_y < swipe_det.sY)) && ((swipe_det.eX < swipe_det.sX + max_x) && (swipe_det.sX > swipe_det.eX - max_x) && (swipe_det.eY > 0)))) {
        if(swipe_det.eY > swipe_det.sY) direc = "down";
        else direc = "up";
    }
    if (direc != "") {
        if(typeof func == 'function') func(el,direc);
    }
    direc = "";
    swipe_det.sX = 0; swipe_det.sY = 0; swipe_det.eX = 0; swipe_det.eY = 0;
},false);
}

function myfunc(el,d){
 if(d=="up"){
   console.log("do Some Work!!");//or any function which you want to call on swipe up/down(matter of prespective,change "up" to down if you want the other way).
 }
}
```

It detects swipe direction by touchevents.
I used this function in my project and it works perfectly fine on all touch devices :)

Answer (score 0):

I've had success using Hammer.js in the past. You can do this natively, but I think it's overall easier to use Hammer.js.

https://hammerjs.github.io/

Comment: Would you have any advice on to incorporate this into standard JavaScript, as I am unable to quite get my head around hammer.js. IE: and example??

Comment: I'd say have a read through https://hammerjs.github.io/getting-started/, it's really helpful.

You could also take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/uZjCB/183/ (which isn't mine but I found it useful when I was using hammer!)